# Is there a way to tell if a user is looking at a page?

Tags: notion-api

Not sure if there is a reference to where a person is looking at in the API, but I would like to be able to trigger an event if my screen is on a subpage within Notion. I would figure that your account could reference the page it's loaded on but haven't found anything. Let me know if you guys come up with any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not support this. The only way to know if a person is looking at your page natively is if they are a guest or member of the workspace and you are simultaneously on the page. Then you can see their icon in an active state. Otherwise, it will be greyed out.

Comment: I know there is an unofficial API as well, I'll check back with you on that one.

Comment: Can't comment on the unofficial API. Only that the official API does not support this.